# Check if div only contains inline elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to run a function that executes if a `div` only contains [inline elements](http://www.tutorialchip.com/tutorials/inline-elements-list-whats-new-in-html5/)

I am not sure how to go about this short of having to list out every single block element and checking that the `div` doesn't contain that.

```
$(this).children().each(function(){
    if(this.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'p' || this.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'h1' etc...){
        check = true; //it contains block element so it is not only inline elements
        return false;
     }
});
```

Is there a better way?

**Edit**

To help clarify, I have a content editable `div` and the problem is that the user can delete all the block elements out of the `div`. I need to check this and add a block element to the div.

Comment: `p` and `h1` are block level elements... not inline

Comment: I know I am returning true if there are block elements.

Comment: well that is contrary to what text says

Comment: @charliefl sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Could you explain the goal? This might help get more specific answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to see if those elements are actually block-level, as CSS can change their behavior completely:

```
var has_inline = $('#parent').children().filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('display') !== 'block';
}).length > 0;
```

I'm not sure what you consider `inline-block` to be, so I'll just assume it behaves like an `inline` element for your purposes.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hXckq/2/**

Comment: I'm not sure if e.g. `<span>` element has `display: inline` by default, or `<p>` can't have `display: initial`. As well as I'm quite uncertain about `display: inline-block` property.

Comment: @VisioN: I'm not sure if that's something you can fix. Chrome is defaulting to `inline`: http://i.imgur.com/Lz0RU.png

Comment: This will do for my purposes. Thank you!

Comment: Seems to work like expected for me too -> [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hXckq/5/) - +1

Answer (score 2):

How about [`has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) in jQuery:

```
if ($(this).has("p,h1, ...")) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the inline elements into a hash, then use `in` or `hasOwnProperty`:

```
var inline = {
    "span": true,
    "a": true,
    ...
};

if(this.nodeName.toLowerCase() in inline) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this, check if the css property of each element is indeed inline, this should work though I did not test this syntax may be incorrect:

```
$(this).children().each(function(){
    if($(this).css('display', 'inline') == true){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$(this).css("display", "inline")` will set the CSS property but not check its value.

Comment: Okay, maybe this then: `$(this).css('display') == 'inline'`